# How can I solve application error on heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, error-handling

I am trying to create an app on django and I am trying to host it on heroku. Everything runs perfectly locally. I get an error while trying to migrate the database onto the heroku app by running command -

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 121, in connect
    dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 167, in make_dsn
    parse_dsn(dsn)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "init_command"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1307, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1699, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes or
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/features.py", line 84, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 339, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 614, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 246, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 230, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 211, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 25, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 199, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 121, in connect
    dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 167, in make_dsn
    parse_dsn(dsn)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "init_command"
```

settings.py -

```
prod_db  =  dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)
```

settings.py ( database section ) -

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '****',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue? Please ask if I need to add any of my files onto the question.

Comment: Something is wrong with your database connection string. Are you using Heroku Postgres, or another database service? If you are using Heroku Postgres, are you connecting via the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable?

Comment: I am using MySQL for my database service.

Comment: Where is it hosted? Are you using one of [the addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores)?

Comment: I didn't understand, what do you mean by hosting the database? I just created my database and linked it to django. Although the mysql workbench runs on local host.

Comment: And if you are using MySQL, why does the error message reference `psycopg2`, which is a PostgreSQL driver?

Comment: "I just created my database and linked it to django"—created it... _where?_ "linked it"... _how?_ MySQL Workbench is a database _client_, not a database host. Telling us that it is running on your machine doesn't tell us anything about where the actual server is.

Comment: I created the mysql database using MySQL workbench. After creating everything, I linked the database to the models.py database of the django app in settings.py through the database field.

Comment: Alright, it sounds like you haven't got a hosted database at all. And there's definitely an issue with how your database is configured. Are you using `django_on_heroku` or `dj_database_url`?

Comment: I believe dj-database-url

Comment: Please don't guess... do you have `dj_database_url` listed as a dependency? Please [edit] your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` into your question so we can see. Do you use `dj_database_url` in your `settings.py`? If so, please [edit] the relevant snippet into your question.

Comment: Yes I am using dj_databse_url. This is listed as a dependancy in my requirements.txt and is being used in settings.py ( have added the snippets needed in the question description )

Comment: Thank you. Please your `DATABASES` section, too (make sure to edit the password out). I bet it contains an `init_command`.

Comment: I have updated this snippet on the question

Answer (score 0):

You are using MySQL for local development and *PostgreSQL* in production. The PostgreSQL connection is coming from the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable that `dj_database_url` uses by default.

Since you are updating your default database from the environment (not replacing it), the MySQL-specific `init_command` option is being left in your PostgreSQL configuration. The `psycopg2` PostgreSQL driver doesn't know what to do with it.

A quick and dirty solution would be to completely your default database configuration instead of updating it:

```py
DATABASES['default'] = prod_db
```

But I *strongly* urge you to use the same database server for development and production. As you have discovered, database engines aren't drop-in replacements for each other. In this case, it's likely easiest to switch from PostgreSQL to MySQL on Heroku.

**First, let's get rid of the Postgres stuff:**

- Remove `psycopg2` from your dependencies. Its presence [likely caused Heroku to automatically provision a PostgreSQL database for you](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres), which added to the confusion.
- Optionally, de-provision the existing Postgres database. It's probably the free version so it isn't costing you anything, but it's a bit weird to have it hanging around if you are using a completely different database server.

**Now, provision a MySQL server.** I suggest you pick from [the available addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores). There are a few MySQL options, including JawsDB and ClearDB. Here is [an example using ClearDB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#provisioning-the-shared-mysql-add-on):

```
heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite
```

Ignite is the free tier for ClearDB. Once provisioned, your app will see a new environment variable `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`. Other addons will use other environment variable names, so make sure to read their documentation.

**Finally, update your Django configuration.** `dj_database_url` uses the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable by default, but [we can tell it to use another](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url/blob/1937ed9e61d273163353c8546825dd529ce8546c/dj_database_url.py#L59):

```py
prod_db = dj_database_url.config(env="CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL", conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)
```

Comment: that requires me to have my account verified using a credit card

Comment: Should I then just use postgresql

Comment: @SomSin, it's up to you. But if you do you should switch to PostgreSQL locally as well. Personally, I think switching to MySQL on Heroku is easier (you may find that existing migrations don't work as expected with Postgres, for example). If you have access to a credit card, verification is fairly painless. You won't be billed if you stick with free services.

Comment: @SomSin, if you are able to find another cloud-hosted MySQL server that you can provision without a credit card you could use that instead of an addon via Heroku.

Comment: @SomSin, I added a quick and dirty option near the top that might work without having to change database servers. But I do strongly suggest using one of the other options, with the same server software in both development and production.

Comment: I don't have access to a credit-card so that is not an option for me, I am trying to import all my data from my-sql to postgres but that isn't working either, so what should I do?

Comment: One step at a time. Before you can even think about migrating _data_ you need a running _database_. Have you been able to deploy your application successfully? [The duplicate question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71311815/354577) shows the same error as above.

Comment: Yes, I have been able to deploy my application successfully. It works perfectly locally.

Comment: I'm not asking about locally. Have you been able to deploy the application to Heroku successfully? The duplicate question suggests that you have not.

Comment: Yes, the application has been deployed to heroku successfully. The app runs perfectly until when it is asked to query data from a database.

Comment: "until when it is asked to query data from a database"—and then what happens? The same error as above? Your duplicate question says you are still trying to use MySQL. But it shows the same `psycopg2` error, which suggests you haven't tried any of the things I suggest here. What have you changed since I provided this answer?

Comment: After it is asked to query data, it throws the same error above. I have changed the requirements.txt file to remove the psycopg2 dependancy.

Comment: @SomSin, that was step _one_. But if you didn't deprovision your database the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is still set. And if you didn't change your `dj_database_url` call, it is still using that variable. Have you found a MySQL database provider to use?